# How to calculate Arc Length from a point to a Box projected on a sphere?

Tags: geometry, spheres, arc-length

Lets say I have sphere with radius `r` and center `C`.

If i have two points on the surface of this sphere, say`P1` and `P2`, I can calculate the arc length between these two points on the sphere:

$ArcLength = r*arccos(\frac{(P_1-C).(P_2-C)}{|P_1-C|*|P_2-C|})$

My question is, how do I calculate the arc length between a point `P1` on the sphere and a line segment  `P2P3` projected on the sphere?

Then if I have a box projected on the sphere, I can calculate the length for all four segments and get the closest distance but how do I detect if the point `P1` is inside the box or not? (if point is inside the box, distance should be 0)

P.S. length of the box is always smaller than the diameter of the sphere.

Points are projected to the sphere in this way (`P'` being the projected point)

$P' =\frac{P-C}{|P-C|}*r+C$

To project a line or box to the sphere I simply project each point individually.

Comment: It would be useful to know how the segment is projected onto the sphere. If $P_2$ and $P_3$ are points on the sphere, that is also helpful information.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks. I've added that as well.

Comment: For your inside vs outside  the box question, the first thing you need to do is define which side counts as "inside" and which as "outside". In the plane, this is easy: the side that is unbounded is outside. But on the sphere both sides are bounded. Make sure whatever definition you use, it will work for all possible boxes.